# How to make a two way table from 2 numpy arrays?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have 2 numerical arrays from numpy, `A` and `B` of length `i` and `j` (`i != j`).

I want to make a two-way table with them to compute the difference for each element of `B` with all the elements of `A`.

I know how to compute the difference between each element using for loops, but this prevents me from knowing from which elements `B[i]` and `A[j]` the `C[i][j]` difference was calculated (which I need for further analysis).

I assume this table can be easily created with pandas but don't know which function or how to implement it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add sample data, code, current and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
import numpy as np

# Sample data
x = np.random.randint(0,10,5)
y = np.random.randint(0,10,3)

diff_matrix = x[:,None]-y[None,:]
```

And you get:

```
In [1]: print(x)
[2, 8, 0, 8, 8]

In [2]: print(y)
[7, 0, 6]

In [3]: print(diff_matrix)
[-5,  2, -4],
[ 1,  8,  2],
[-7,  0, -6],
[ 1,  8,  2],
[ 1,  8,  2]]
```

So `diff_matrix[i,j]` is `x[i]-y[j]`

Comment: Yeah, that's nicer than reshape.